# Filling in an online form and parsing response using R

Tags: r, forms

I would like to download historical data from moneycontrol.com and parse the data returned, which is in Date OHLCV format. A request is submitted using this form

http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php?

The form obviously needs a from date and a to date, in addition to company name and the exchange, but I am not sure what variables to assign in the POST command. Here is my effort

```
query <- list(ex = "N", comp = "GAIL",
    frm_dy = "01", frm_mth = "01", frm_yr = "2017",
    to_dy = "01", "to_mth" = "09", to_yr = "2017")
resp2 <- POST("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php?",
    body=query, encode = "form")
```

I got the variable names from the page using "Show Source" in Safari - is there an easier way to figure this out, and have I even got it right?

I get a 200 status code response, but am unable to parse the data to check whether the output is there or whether I get an empty page with no data.

New to SO and I havent been able to find an answer to this on the web, so would appreciate any help on how to proceed!

Thanks!

Comment: google: "Automated data scraping from websites". Maybe you find something that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have to spend some time learning how to get this done using the resources you suggest! Thanks!